# Mac logs Network and remotely (what do the logs look like)

Tags: ssh, osx, logs, login

How do I find out if someone has been on my computer remotely or through a network?  I am on a network with quite a few different people at my house.

Comment: Use the logs, Luke ...

Answer (score 0):

The command `last` from a terminal window will show you a history of logins.